# c# object visible in the Locals from Visual Studio, but not usable in the Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wonder why when I look in the Locals in Debugging Mode, I have an Object SelectElements, but I'm not able to use it in the code visual studio is not displaying it in the dropdown, and it also brings a error message, that the object or method doesn't exists...
What am I missing ? If it is a scope problem, why is it visible in debugging ?

```
      TSqlParser parser = new TSql120Parser(true);
        IList<ParseError> parseErrors;
        TSqlFragment sqlFragment = parser.Parse(new StringReader(sql), out parseErrors);

        if (parseErrors.Count > 0) Console.WriteLine("Errors:");
        //parseErrors.Select(e => e.Message.Indent(2)).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        OwnVisitor visitor = new OwnVisitor();
        sqlFragment.Accept(visitor);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class OwnVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public override void ExplicitVisit(SelectStatement node)
    {
        QuerySpecification querySpecification = node.QueryExpression as QuerySpecification;

        FromClause fromClause = querySpecification.FromClause;
        NamedTableReference namedTableReference = fromClause.TableReferences[0] as NamedTableReference;
        TableReferenceWithAlias tableReferenceWithAlias = fromClause.TableReferences[0] as TableReferenceWithAlias;

        foreach (var with in node.WithCtesAndXmlNamespaces.CommonTableExpressions)
        {
            var = with.QueryExpression.s

            //QuerySpecification wQs = with.QueryExpression;
        }
```

[image: Visual Studio]

Comment: Most often you need a cast. The watch and Locals window can dig into the real object, they know the real type at runtime. The source code does not, it knows only the abstract type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The locals window shows a real shape of object with all fields/properties (even if it is private or not exposed by interface), whereas Visual Studio show only available members (allowed by current interface). For example:

```
interface IFoo { }
```

```
class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

```
void Method()
{
    IFoo foo = new Bar();
    foo.Prop; // Here, you will see error from VS, but still can see/update it in Locals
}
```

So, in your case, just check a type of you variable in Locals window (third column) and actual type in code, probably, they are different.